# How do you 'unraw' a raw string in python?

Tags: python

Is there a way to take a raw string/literal string in python and interpret it as a regular string.  For example.

```
>>> a = r'un\x00'
>>> len(a)
6
```

What can I do to 'a' to make len(a) = 3

Comment: Why did you write a raw string literal if you wanted a regular string literal?

Comment: This is a perfect example of the kind of thing our duplicate system is meant for -- finding a case where we already have a question answered, but with a completely different description / set of search terms.

Comment: On the linked duplicate, I prefer the solutions that use `ast.literal_eval`. A one-liner might be like `import ast; b = ast.literal_eval("'''%s'''" % a)`. Quoting might get a bit tricky, but the use of the triple quotes around the string helps.